# Django annotation based on multiple columns

Tags: python, django

So in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) there is the following annotation example:

```
Book.objects.annotate(Count('authors'))
```

which then allows you to do fun things like sort depending on the amount of authors. I would like to do the following:

```
Example.objects.annotate(value=sum('column1','column2','column5'))
```

now of course this does not work, but it shows what I want: to add `value` which is the `sum` of the numbers in a row that are in the first, second, and fifth column.

How can you annotate based on **multiple** column values in each row?

Comment: I don't think the Django ORM exposes the ability to do this. See this feature request: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14030 Assuming I'm not forgetting anything, you'd have to either do the math in Python or use an `extra` clause on your queryset to add the appropriate SQL to your query.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I don't see how the `extra` clause would make this possible. I need the annotation because I will use these numbers later, and extra would  only let me do things with the `value` in the moment (I think at least). I would rather not do the math in python because that would most likely end up evaluating the `QuerySet`, which I do not want to happen here. I also cannot add this as an extra column in my db either. So editing the model is out of the question. So are you saying that this is impossible?

Comment: `extra` lets you add extra fields to your select, which will then be present as an attribute on the model instances similar to annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do this with `extra`:

```
Example.objects.extra(select={'value': 'column1 + column2 + column3'})
```

And to filter, I believe you need to use a `where` clause repeating the math:

```
Example.objects.extra(select={'value': 'column1 + column2 + column3'},
                      where=['(column1 + column2 + column3) >= %s'],
                      params=[100])
```

Or whatever logic is appropriate.

Comment: oh I thought extra did not add the value and simply let you do things based on it in the moment. So then what is the difference from `extra` and `annotate`?

Comment: `annotate` is more consistent across different database back ends, and I think it's easier to set up `GROUP BY` queries using the annotation calls. And I know you can filter on annotation values - I don't recall offhand whether you could further filter the above based on `value`.

Comment: is it possible for `extra` to give any problems with Postsgres?

Comment: As for postgres - I very much doubt it for a simple query like this, but test it and see. For filtering, you can force it in with a `where` clause in the `extra` as well. See this discussion for why SQL makes this not something you can easily automate: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/8hUxv0WdZi8

Comment: One quick thing I don't understand...in the `where` clause, how can you have a '%s' and what does that even mean? I'm just confused on the syntax of the `where` clause

Comment: That causes the queryset to automatically escape the values in the `params` list and interpolate them into the `where` clause to avoid being vulnerable to SQL injection. The docs have some detail and more examples. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra